# Join two tables by one to one mapping of matching substring In SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

[enter image description here][image: 1]

The two tables needs to be joined based on the substring matching of the suffix with the URL

Comment: Please check out [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `LIKE` in the join predicate, as in:

```
select *
from urls u
join suffixes s on u.url like concat('%', s.suffix)
```